# VBA Access How to display Search Results in main form

Tags: ms-access, vba

in my user search form i display a user and when i click the search button i  would like to open this record in my main user details form.

The current code i have for this is in my UserSearch form is below.
The User# is the primary key field in the main UserDetails form

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
  'open record in user details form
  'record set is set to that users number so when the form is closed
  'the main form will display the selected record

Dim strUserNo As String

    strUserNo = Me.cboUser_.Value
    rstUserSearch.FindFirst ("[User#] = " & strUserNo & "'")

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserDetails", , , "[User#] = " & strUserNo

End Sub
```

The code to call this in my main form is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    'create a connection with the current database
    Call setDatabaseConnection
    'create a set of user detail records
    Set rstUserDetails = dbase.OpenRecordset("tblUser", dbOpenDynaset)

  'if record opened from another form
    Dim strUser As String

    If Not IsNull(Forms!frmUserDetails.OpenArgs) Then
        strUser = Forms!frmUserDetails.OpenArgs
        rstUserDetails.FindFirst ("[User#] = '" & strUser & "' ")
    End If

   'make all text boxes read-only and greyed out ...
    txtuser_.Locked = False
    txtuser_.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtForename.Locked = False
    txtForename.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtSurname.Locked = False
    txtSurname.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtDepartment.Locked = False
    txtDepartment.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtEmail.Locked = False
    txtEmail.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtPhoneNo.Locked = False
    txtPhoneNo.BackColor = &HCCCECC
    txtComputerNo.Locked = False
    txtComputerNo.BackColor = &HCCCECC


End Sub
```

This way of doing it only opens the form but does not show the required record so any help would be great!

I have added the following also but recieve the error 'object variable not set'

```
Dim db As Database

    Set rstUserSearch = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUser.* FROM tblUser ORDER BY tblUser.[User#];")
```

Comment: "has proven unsuccessful" which means?

Comment: This means it opens the form but does not show the record i have selected

Answer (score 0):

To call the form you use:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserDetails", , , "[User#] = " & strUserNo
```

I think it should be

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserDetails", , , "[User#] = '" & strUserNo & "'"
```

And second, in your `Form_Load` event, you got:

```
If Not IsNull(Forms!frmUserDetails.OpenArgs) Then
        strUser = Forms!frmUserDetails.OpenArgs
        rstUserDetails.FindFirst ("[User#] = '" & strUser & "' ")
End If
```

I think you could delete all that, because you are opening your form applying a WHERE CONDITION (A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE.) . You would filter by [User#], your primary key field, so it should work.

Comment: After updating the call event  i recieve the runtime error '2492' - the error is invaid because the form is not bound to a table or query.
It seems the primary key field may be the issue

Comment: Make sure the Recordset source of your form is bounded to the table/query that contains the data you want to show, including the field [User#]

Comment: I have updated this and it produces an error - see updated question for code

Comment: your variable `db` is nothing. You should set it to your current database. Or try with `Set rstUserSearch = Application.Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblUser.* FROM tblUser ORDER BY tblUser.[User#];")`